# How to center text labels on a density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a density plot with annotated vertical lines at specific points, but I've run into a problem specifying the y value for geom_text.

The code runs fine if I specify a y value, but if the dataset changes then the y limits can also change, causing the text to be in the wrong place. For example:

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

all_data <- iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]
setosa_data <- filter(all_data, Species == "setosa")

labels <- data.frame(label_text = c("label_1", "label_2"), label_position = c(4.75, 5.5))

ggplot(setosa_data, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = labels$label_position) + 
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x=label_position, y = 0.8), label = labels$label_text, vjust=-0.5, size=4, angle = 90)

ggplot(all_data, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = labels$label_position) + 
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x=label_position, y = 0.8), label = labels$label_text, vjust=-0.5, size=4, angle = 90)
```

In the above examples I've set y = 0.8 which is fine for the first dataset, but is much too high on the second dataset.

I think that I want to specify y as a function of the y limits so I can tell geom_text to plot the text halfway between the upper and lower limits, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick and dirty approach:

```
ggplot(all_data, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = labels$label_position, lty = 2, colour = "gray50") + 
  geom_text(
    data = labels, 
    aes(x=label_position, y = median(density(all_data$Sepal.Length)$y)), 
    label = labels$label_text, vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0, 
    size = 4, angle = 90, colour = "gray50"
    ) +
  ggthemes::theme_few()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a slightly round-about solution by creating the plot, using ggplot_build to extract the y limits and taking the mean to get the middle point.

```
my_plot <- ggplot(all_data, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
geom_density() +
geom_vline(xintercept = labels$label_position) 

text_position <- mean(ggplot_build(my_plot)$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range)

my_plot + geom_text(data = labels, aes(x=label_position, y = text_position), label = 
labels$label_text, vjust=-0.5, size=4, angle = 90)
```